# How to delay successive iterations of a loop in MOAI?

Tags: loops, lua, delay, moai

I want to delay successive iteration of a loop in MOAI. I've tried using a timer to delay calling the loop, and putting an empty loop inside my main loop. In the latter case, it just goes through all iterations of the inner loop before proceeding to the outer loop. The result is, it stops at the first iteration of the main loop, then goes through the inner loop, and then finally executes the the main loop. How do I stop it from happening?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you want to make happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to look at the code, but assuming you wrap your loop into MOAICoroutine, you can use `coroutine.yield()` to yield out of the loop and then use `coroutine.resume()` to return to it when your delay condition is satisfied. Since it's not a "busy" loop, your application may continue working on other tasks.

Comment: The whole code for the game is in a single thread, and it depends completely on user input. There is no "game loop".

Comment: And I don't want it to do other stuff while waiting. I just need it to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I suspect what you should do is call [MOAICoroutine.blockOnAction](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_coroutine.html#a00f1fe1b5db286b0762a500f93646faa) on a timer, something like:

```
local timer = MOAITimer.new()
timer:setSpan(5)
MOAICoroutine.blockOnAction(timer:start())
```